# SQL query to check the amout of repeated messages within X minutes ?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate-functions

Is there a query where I could match if field cmd has been sent more then 3 times with the same content in the last 15 minutes ?

I currently have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `log` 
WHERE gid = @gid 
AND ts_register BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

Which will gather me all the messages sent in the last 15 minutes by the global id.

Is there a way to take the field cmd into consideration and list if the gid has sent a repeated cmd more then 3 times within the last 15 minutes ?

for example:

```
gid 1 cmd testing repeatable cmd
gid 1 cmd testing repeatable cmd
gid 1 cmd testing repeatable cmd
gid 1 cmd different cmd
```

So it would give me the count of 3.

Comment: Cant you add the `cmd` column in your query e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*), cmd FROM etc.`

Comment: Neil Knight, I wanted to match the CMD field within the query and return only the count

Comment: I should have put it as an answer as @Adrian has beat me to it.

Comment: @Neil Knight yeah, I was not aware the GROUP BY would work in that way, that is pretty nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
SELECT cmd, COUNT(*) Qty
FROM `log` 
WHERE gid = @gid 
AND ts_register BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
GROUP BY cmd
```

Given your data, that would return:

```
Cmd                                  Qty
---                                  ---
gid 1 cmd testing repeatable cmd     3
gid 1 cmd different cmd              1
```

**Update**

Using @Gidon's suggestion (Upvoted you, man!), you can add a `HAVING` clause to display only the ones with more than 3:

```
SELECT cmd, COUNT(*) Qty
FROM `log` 
WHERE gid = @gid 
AND ts_register BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
GROUP BY cmd
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

Comment: damn, that is easy hehehe, wasnt aware I could use group by like that.

Comment: using `HAVING` i get total of the messages instead of only the count `group by cmd`

Comment: Is that a question? If so, I could not understand it. Would you mind rephrasing?

Comment: for example, if i use just group by without having, it will display the above result, using having it will display the total count of the given gid instead.

Answer (score 2):

add this to Adrian's query to get your more than 3 criteria in.

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

Comment: @GidonWise nice thing thx. Using this it will not take into consideration the `GROUP BY` it seems

Comment: HAVING and GROUP BY are buddies. HAVING is like a WHERE except it relates to the output of the GROUP BY. WHERE happens before the GROUP BY touches a query.

Comment: @GidonWise I am a bit confused now, so basicly I either use WHERE or HAVING or HAVING should come together with the WHERE ?

Comment: you can use both. here's an exampe.   select count(*) as parts from inventory where type='cars' group by model having parts > 3;  so you can see that we restrict it to cars before we do the group by. and then we eliminate results with HAVING using parts after the group by when parts is defined.

Comment: @GidonWise well it doesn't seem to be working like that for me, image a chat with several messages and I am filtering the messages by user id grouping by message text which will give me the total amount of repeated messages a user has sent, if i use HAVING it will not give me all the messages that were repeated more then 3 times within 15 minutes but the total number of messages he sent in 15 minutes.

Comment: AND ts_register BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
this is the part of the query in the WHERE that does the 15 minute filtering. and the HAVING filters the total's by those that have 3.

Comment: @GidonWise like I said if I remove the HAving the result is as expect, if i leave the Having in there it will just show me the total meesages without grouping them by cmd